# Comparing an item in a list against other items in the same list in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Simplified, I have a `List(Of MyObj)`, and I want to iterate through that list and compare each element to all other elements in the *same* list, excluding (if possible) the same element.  I have a solution that works, but it's slow and uses double For loops.  It may possibly have also summoned Cthulhu from his sleep.

Is there a better approach?  Linq, perhaps?  Or some fancy algorithm?  This below is a sanitized version of what I have:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of MyObj)({Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4, Obj5, Obj6})

If MyList.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To (MyList.Count - 1) Step 1
        For j As Int32 = 0 To (MyList.Count - 1) Step 1
            If MyList(i).GetHashCode = MyList(j).GetHashCode Then
                Continue For
            Else
                If MyList(i).SomeFunction(MyList(j)) Then
                    Call DoSomething()
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Else
    ' Error Code Here.
End If
```

Comment: Getting a match on `GetHashCode` for two objects is no guarantee that the objects are equal.  This is _not_ what GetHashCode is for.

Comment: Could you provide more information as to what you actually want to do with the list elements - what is the ultimate goal of comparing each element to each other element?

Comment: I stated in the large comment thread on hamlin11's answer.  Check there.  SO really needs to re-jig the way comments work on this site...

Comment: @Kumba, SO founders intend content to be xferred from comments into answers / questions as it becomes relevant. Just letting you know that that is the solution they have come up with to solve the issue. They really view questions and answers as wikis.

Comment: @hamlin11: They could at least allow paragraphs in comments.

Comment: @Kumba You are correct, I'm just letting you know their intentions. They basically understand that 90% of visitors will never view the comments, so they want to encourage everything to move to the questions/answers. Just letting you know their intentions on the matter. I imagine they've weighed the pro's & con's, but nobody's perfect

Comment: @hamlin11: What SO has here is a programmer's heaven, so I'm not complaining __that__ loudly.  Half the questions I've asked would get slapped down in any other forum for being too n00bish.  And while EE is another good place (at times), the way they carpet bomb Google's results have caused me to practically disown them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in O(M*N) where N is ObjCount and M is the number of non-duplicate objects. Your current solution is O(N^2).

1. You need a Hash Function. You can determine whether `GetHashCode` will suffice or whether you need to implement Sha1.
2. Instantiate a `HashSet` (or `HashTable`, depending on your Hash Function)
3. Add each object, if it does not already exist, into the `HashSet` or `HashTable`.
4. For each object in the `HashSet`, execute `SomeFunction()` against every other object in the `HashSet`. If you dump into an array and iterate via indexes, you only have to compare indexes, rather than objects.

   ```
   For i as integer = 0 to MyHashResultsArray.Count - 1
     For j as integer = 0 to MyHashResultsArray.Count - 1
       if i <> j then
         MyHashResultsArray(i).DoSomething(j)
       end if
     next
   next
   ```

**Important**

This is only a good solution IF there exists a significant amount of duplicates, perhaps a duplicate-level of 10% would be necessary to consider this solution, except for very large values of N. If N gets too large, a re-engineering of the application may be necessary to hopefully avoid the need for M actions against M objects.

**Edit**

Much of the comment discussion was based upon my misunderstanding of the Author's needs regarding the DoSomething() function.

Comment: As the OP states, all objects need to be compared to all other objects (and DoSomething() for each pair) - so an O(N) solution is not possible here - the algorithm must be O(N^2) unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Sure it's possible, read my answer. And yes, hash functions are adequate for comparison if you're OK with many 9's accuracy (sha1 is fast and very unique). However, if you'd rather rely on theoretical (and slow) perfection... then a O(N^2) will certainly suffice.

Comment: But to `DoSomething()` for each pair (except reference-identical objects) requires O(N^2) operations.

Comment: Computing a hash for each element once does not cause it to go form N to N^2. It makes it O(M*N) where M is the speed of the hash function. I appreciate your criticism, but if we're going to fall back on theory it's important to be accurate.

Comment: @hamlin11 it doesn't matter how unique SHA1 is, GetHashCode returns an Integer, so you'll only get 2^32 possibly values.  Unless the hashcode is designed to be unique for a particular Class, be prepared for collisions.

Comment: @hamlin11, totally agree re: computing hashes - it doesn't matter how fast the hash is, if the hash does not relate in any way to the size of the list the runtime is still O(N) for the computing-all-hashes part.

Comment: 32bits is not adequate for a hash value. 160 bits is standard.

Comment: Edited answer to suggest a minimum level of hash function should be used

Comment: Ok I see where you're getting it from -- I was speaking in terms of Hash Tables in general, rather than the .NET implementation. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I will adjust my answer so that they use the .NET Dictionary.

Comment: I have hash functions on all of my objects.  I've actually opened a question here specifically on doing a **sane** hash function because VB lacks checked/unchecked keywords, and the chances of an overflow are high if one uses all the C# hash functions out there (I even tried a Jenkins Hash and it didn't survive the first few transformations).  So the hash function I have is about as good as it'll get in VB until MS adds checked/unchecked support.

Comment: Use Sha1. It's fast. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx

Comment: @hamlin11 - no problem.  I think it's also important to note that in the OP, `DoSomething` will run approximately N^2 times - so runtime will be O(N^2) wrt. the size of the collection.

Comment: PS, seems I stirred an interesting thread here, give me a bit to read and understand and test some things.

Comment: @hamlin11: Can't.  GetHashCode returns an Int32, so that's what my hash functions all return.  I wish MS offered other overloads or had SHA1 hashing built in natively (Natively as an override in Object -- I know SHA1 and other hashes are available in the crypto libs).

Comment: @Will -- It will run O(N^2) in the OP, but not in my answer. Only N times in my answer.

Comment: @Kumba, please note that my proposed solution only really starts to help you once you get into thousands and more objects. However, it is almost infinitely faster than standard N^2 methods once N gets very large. Buckets can be your friend!

Comment: @hamlin11: I'll know the speed soon once I catch up to all the comments.

Comment: @hamlin11 - I just can't see that - as written the OP describes an algorithm that can only be O(N^2).

Comment: @Kumba, you can use a HashSet, but I would go with HashTable or Dictionary so that you can manage your keys easier.

Comment: @Will - Think of it this way. Drop each object in a list into a bucket. If the bucket is already full, Perform action, DoSomething(). Otherwise, Add the object to the empty bucket. Each object processed once. I did not detect ambiguity in this respect in the question, but I could be wrong. Depending on the Author's other  needs, he can store indexes to "duplicate" objects in a data structure of his/her choice, for example, if each object needs to know about its twins.

Comment: @hamlin11 - but what about `if MyList(i).SomeFunction(MyList(j)) ...`?

Comment: @hamlin11 - have added a comment to OP to ask for clarification - as it's not totally clear what's required - we could be 'barking up the wrong tree'.

Comment: Okay, let me clarify, the Objects in question in the list are IPv4 addresses.  I wrote my own custom class for representing IPv4, so technically, there is an upper limit that just so happens to be the same as the maximum value for an Int32 (or UInt32).  The chances of a hash collision are small in that case.  Now, the same cannot be said for my IPv6 objects.  In that case, I have to accept the chance of a collision.  And really, there's no harm in running SomeFunction() on the same object, because all SomeFunction really is, is a range check to see if IP A is inside of IP B if B is a range.

Comment: @Will - you pointed out the ambiguity in the question. I see it now. However, reading his paragraph and the rest of the code -- my solution is perfect. However, If each Non-Duplicate object needs to be executed against each other Non-Duplicate object, then there is indeed no solution better than Worst-Case O(N^2).  Sorry for the confusion again -- I was focused in on his text-based requirement.

Comment: @hamlin11 - not a problem, I certainly wasn't intending to criticize your solution, I think we've been fighting (!) at crossed purposes - for something that isn't totally clear...

Comment: PS, my ambiguity in the question was to provide a clear testcase so as to not invite discussion on unrelated side-tangents of the code I'm working on (which has happened before).

Comment: @Kumba - consider _not_ using GetHashCode for equality comparison, but otherwise your code as written is perfectly adequate - you won't be able to squeeze much more out of it _if_ you require approximately N^2 comparisons.

Comment: @Will: It's not that I require N^2 comparisons, I just figured what I was doing was not as efficient as it could be, and rather than scouring Google and running into dead ends, I figured I'd ask here and see what better minds think.  I'll take the fastest that I can get as long as it doesn't require completely gutting the internal plumbing of these objects.

Comment: Also, I don't think I have a choice in overriding GetHashCode.  .NET relies on it internally for a lot of things, and the default formula used in System.Object is quite slow.  That said, I'm open to other ideas for equality (I do have = and <> overloaded, which utilize GetHashCode and HashSets, plus IComparable, IEquatable, and IEqualityComparer implemented).

Comment: @Kumba -- if you are suitable with the amount of collisions that you may get using your GetHashCode() results, then using a HashSet will provide the least overhead (programming-wise). Otherwise, you can invest in Sha1 & the coding infrastructure to support using a HashTable or Dictionary. Good luck, thanks for sparking a fun discussion

Comment: @hamlin11: So with your solution, assume I use a HashSet (and the .Contains() method of the HashSet), what are the structural changes needed to still iterate over the HashSet and check an object against all other objects via the SomeFunction() call?  I.e., how can I ditch the double for loops?

Comment: @Kumba, in your question -- SomeFunction() is only executed on non-duplicate objects. Is this the intent? Do you want this to be called between all non-duplicate Objects? In other words, if there are M unique objects, do you want all M objects to execute this function against one another? That is where I am unclear. In fact, @Will's and my discussion only occurred due to this lack of understanding regarding this SomeFunction()

Comment: @hamlin11: Yes.  For all non-duplicate objects, I want to run SomeFunction().  SomeFunction is really just a range check for IPv4.  I.e., if I have `4.1.1.0/24` and `4.1.0.0/16` in the list, the goal is designed to toss out an error (or do other checks) because `4.1.1.0/24` can fit inside `4.1.0.0/16`, and thus, the objects are basically duplicates (for all intents and purposes).

Comment: Ok, I will adjust my answer. One moment

Comment: To further iterate, I have IPv4 objects and IPv6 objects.  I have a third Object that represents a "network address", and internally, it holds both an IPv4 __or__ IPv6.  There are checks done internally to NetAddr that determine whether it returns an IPv4 or IPv6 address.  NetAddr, in turn, is the object I so eloquently call `MyObj` in my opening statement that fits into the List.  So in theory, before I can ever call SomeFunction(), I have to first determine the internal type of NetAddr -- is it an IPv4 range check I need or an IPv6 range check?  But that is trivial to do.

Comment: @hamlin11: Very nice!  That said, there should only ever exist one duplicate -- the same item being compared to the other items in the this, which we skip over.  It is technically an error if any additional duplicates are found.  So I'll never have a 10% duplicate ratio.  In fact, in 90% of the cases, the list may, at most, have no more than 4-8 objects.  But the list construct is used twice, because of source and destination address groupings.  I also have similar lists for network ports, but those are a LOT simpler.

Comment: @Kumba, well, this solution allows you to remove all duplicates (a byproduct of jamming everything into a HashSet). That might allow your double-loop to go a bit quicker. Shouldn't take long to compare solutions. Furthermore, I suppose, my solution also computes hashes once, instead of N-1 times for each object. Perhaps it'll be faster anyway. Good luck

Comment: Need clarification on something: Is a HashSet/HashTable faster to loop through than a simple List(Of MyObj)?  Your code is virtually similar to what I have, minus that I am using a List.  I actually replaced my GetHashCode check with "i = j" from your example, and that alone shaved a bit of time off the testing loop (which looped things over 10,000 times).

Comment: I don't think it will be any slower iterating through a HashSet, but I have not compared them directly. I think the reduction in Hash Function executions will offset any additional iterator processing. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/IteratethroughelementsofHashSet.htm

Comment: @hamlin11: Yeah, java2s is a great resource.  That's a Java example, though.  Not sure how applicable to VB.NET it is, though I will state I have not investigated IEnumerable on any of my objects, nor ever tried designing my own custom iterator.  I figured what .NET had built-in was fairly efficient.

Comment: C# from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx   private static void DisplaySet(HashSet<int> set)
    {
        Console.Write("{");
        foreach (int i in set)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}", i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" }");
    }

Comment: @hamlin11: I actually played once (early in development) with just using HashSets all over the place instead of Lists.  I forget what my benchmarks were back then, but Lists whipped a HashSet for general stuff.  The HashSets only come into play (so far) when I overloaded `Operator =`, in which once I checked the left and right operands for simpler things, I dimmed new left and right hashsets and then did a quick `For Each x In left, is right.Contains(x) true?`, and that was pretty fast.

Comment: I also have yet to really dive into Linq, and wonder if Bala R's solution has any merit.  Once I can get it to compile.

Comment: Marking as the answer.  I played around with other ways to do this, including HashSets, a few of the Linq set functions, shifting things around to static functions, etc.  Only real payoffs were flipping the order of comparisons (i.e., checking a boolean before a custom object, which is WAY faster) and merging a conditional or two w/ AndAlso.  It seems I am stuck with O(M*N) in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

See if this will work

```
MyList.Select(Function(x) MyList.Except(New () {x}).ToList().ForEach(Sub(y) Do
    If x.SomeFunction(y) Then
        DoSomething()
    End If
End Sub))
```

Comment: Not to leave you in the dust, but with your solution, I cannot access a `ToList()` member after `Except(x)`.  I have `System.Linq` imported.  Anything else missing?

Comment: @Kumba instead of `x` in Except, it has to be `New () {x}` (see my edit). But this solution is very similar to having two loops except the internals are taken care of with linq.

Comment: The operand to `Select` is still getting flagged as invalid.  It's barking about an overload not being satisfied because it expects 'x' to be of a selector of `System.Func(Of MyObj, Integer, TResult) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)`.  Because of that, the `Except` clause won't populate properly when I try to do auto-complete, and it's got the whole thing flagged as bad.

Answer (score 1):

Barring any potential problems with using GetHashCode to check for object equality (best not to do this - it'll only bite you at some point - and it's probably this that has awakened Cthulhu!), your solution is about as fast as it's likely to get.

Sure, you can tweak it, but it will remain O(N^2), that is, the runtime will be of the order of the square of the number of elements in your list.  If you double the number of elements, your runtime will increase by a factor of 4.